# Generating an encrypted file on a webpage daily

Tags: python

I have a python program that reads an encrypted file to extract the required settings and time. The encrypted file should be updated per each minute and should be accessed remotely by multiple users.

Is there a way to generate that encrypted file on a webpage (with a fixed hyperlink; say [www.website-name.com/log.txt](http://www.website-name.com/log.txt)) and replaces the older file at a specific time frame (for example, per minute, hourly, daily, etc). Then, I can access that file from its url.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install redis on server and install redis-py
reference link https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

```
$ pip install redis
```

then add this to program

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
file_name = ''
# 60 can change to any time you want
expire_time = 60

encrypted_file_content = r.get('file_content')
if not encrypted_file_content:
    encrypted_file_content = do_something()
    r.set('file_content',encrypted_file_content,expire_time)

with open(file_name,'w') as f:
    f.write(encrypted_file_content)
```